# Why some cardinals have their names in yellow?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

In Europa Universalis 4, on the Papacy screen some of the cardinals have their names in yellow color, what does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The yellow color indicates that the cardinal is under the influence of the current curia controller.